# How to test component that uses reactivity api in a vue3 using vitest

Tags: vuejs3, vitest

I'm using the [simple state management with Reactivity API](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) .

I would like to test my component that depends on the store. How to mock the store?

```
// store.js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export const store = reactive({
  count: 0
})
```

```
<!-- ComponentA.vue -->
<script setup>
import { store } from './store.js'
</script>

<template>{{ store.count }}</template>
```

And finally the test:

```
import { expect } from "vitest";

test("shows correct count", async () => {
  const view = customRender(<ComponentA>Test</ComponentA>);
  expect(await view.findByText("10")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple, so I guess nobody bothered putting it anywhere:

```
import { expect } from "vitest";
import { store } from "@/stores/store";

test("shows correct count", async () => {
  store.count = 10;
  const view = customRender(<ComponentA>Test</ComponentA>);
  expect(await view.findByText("10")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Hope it helps. As always, enjoy.